Abbyy Finereader for Mac splits cells in tables
I want to digitize a list of names in Japanese, in vertical text, in a relatively clean table format, and I manually defined the table structure on the page. However, when I copy the cells to excel, some but not all of the vertically oriented cells are broken up into multiple cells, making it difficult to extract the names in one string. How can I force each cell to be exported as one cell instead of getting split?
Screenshot

I manually defined the table structure so that each name gets exported as a single cell but when I copy the table into excel, the cells get split arbitrarily for most cells.

Did you enclose the names with quotes?  Or maybe try separate them with tabs instead.

... And supply a space when there is noting!
